# Cannot inherit ionic global class

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to inherit `.ion-padding-vertical` in a component CSS class.

I tried importing the global SASS file (`/src/global.scss`) file, but it didn't work. I also tried importing the specific file `~@ionic/angular/css/padding.css` as it is done by the global SASS file. However, the compiler cannot find `.ion-padding-vertical` class.

Here is my file.

#### my.component.scss

```
@import "../../../global.scss";

.my-class {
  @extend .ion-padding-vertical;
}
```

Is it possible to inherit an Ionic global CSS class? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.ion-padding-vertical** is not a class that you can change and also *it is not declared in* `global.scss`. it is a *built-in* class. you can check it by searching that class through the project directory to see there is no result.
but if you put your self written class in `global.scss` you can extend it anywhere. (also you can extend classes that already exist in `global.scss`). you also don't need to import anything anywhere. just write your class at the end of `global.scss` and then use it with `@extend` in your `component.scss`

Comment: Indeed I had searched for it in my proejct and got no results because, as you said , it is a built-in class. Thanks, @Mahdi Zarei.

Comment: But anyway, it would be good to be able to use built-in classes, so it would be possible to use them in a component SCSS / CSS instead of adding them to the HTML / ionic tag.